# Applying substitution $v=y/x$ to solve $(x\sin(y/x) - y\cos(y/x))dx + x\cos(y/x)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $(x\sin(y/x) - y\cos(y/x))dx + x\cos(y/x)dy = 0$

I am almost sure that this is to be solved by substitution (I could be wrong though), and the closest I've been is making
$$
v = \frac{y}{x}\\  
y = xv  \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = xdv + v\\
$$
Before this substitution I tried to simplify it by doing
$$
x\sin\frac{y}{x} - y\cos\frac{y}{x} + x\cos v \frac{dy}{dx}= 0  \\
- y\cos\frac{y}{x} + x\cos\frac{y}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} = - x\sin\frac{y}{x} \\
\cos\frac{y}{x} * (x-y)\frac{dy}{dx} = - x\sin\frac{y}{x}  \\
(x-y)\frac{dy}{dx} = - x\frac{\sin\frac{y}{x}}{\cos\frac{y}{x}} \\
\frac{-(x-y)}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sin\frac{y}{x}}{\cos\frac{y}{x}} \\
\frac{-(x-y)}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} = Tan(y/x)$$
And after the substitution

$$
((x-xv) / -x) * (xdv+v) = \tan(v)\\
-(x^2dv - x^2vdv + xv - xv^2) / x = \tan(v)\\
-xdv + xvdv - v + v^2 = \tan(v)
$$

The problem is that after this step I'm pretty sure I did something wrong somewhere, I'm not really even sure that this is the substitution I should be trying, but when I tried to do one with the whole trigonometric functions instead of just the arguments it didn't work out either. How to solve this?

Comment: please use tex to make your content more readable

Comment: Use MathJax please ... Your equations are not readable.

Comment: Sorry, didn't even know how to use that. Thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is here :

[image]

But, even corrected, that do not lead to anything.

Why not simply remplace all the $y$ by $xv$ into the ODE ?

$$x\sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) - y\cos\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + x\cos\left( \frac{y}{x}\right) \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$

$$x\sin\left(v\right) - xv\cos\left(v\right) + x\cos\left( v\right) \left(x\frac{dv}{dx}+v\right) = 0$$

$$x\sin\left(v\right) + x^2\cos\left( v\right) \frac{dv}{dx} = 0$$

$$\frac{\cos(v)}{\sin(v)}dv=-\frac{dx}{x}$$

Then, the integration is straightforward. I am sure that you can continue.

Answer (score 0):

setting $u=y/x$ then you will get $$y'=u'x+u$$ and we will have
$$x\sin(u)-ux\cos(u)+x^2u'\cos(u)+xu\cos(u)=0$$ simplifying we have
$$x\sin(u)+x^2\cos(u)\frac{du}{dx}=0$$
and we get $$u(x)=\arcsin\left(\frac{e^c}{x}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm confused about that last step though. I guess it was some identity + integration on both sides?